# How to get best performance while reading a byte array into chunks? MemoryStream or Buffer.BlockCopy?

Tags: c#, performance, arrays, memorystream

I have a code where I have to read data from byte array into chunks of 32KB. The original byte[] could be of size from 100KB to 1MB.

Right now I am using Buffer.BlockCopy in loop to create another byte array of 32KB from the original byte array. This implementation is relatively difficult to implement then by using MemoryStream since it provides a good way of reading in chunks.

This part of my code executes frequently. So I need a way which can give best performance.

Should I first convert the byte array into memorystream or directly reading with buffer.blockcopy is best option?

Thanks

Comment: Do whatever is easiest to implement, then optimize for performance if performance is a measurable problem.  For your specific application, there may not be a tangible difference in performance between the two options.

Comment: Do you want the data to be copied or is a reference to the original data ok?

Comment: @david I want it to be copied into new byte array.

Answer (score 2):

I have conducted benchmarks in the past and *Buffer.BlockCopy* is almost always faster than *Array.Copy*. In fact, according to my tests if you're working with a buffer larger than ~128kb then [*memcp*](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msvcrt.memcpy) performs the fastest but of course, this is all relative.

Here are some micro-benchmark results:

[image]

But at the end of the day: *["If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)*"